# OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (((((sizeof(size_t)<<28)|0x8442211).... line 957

Tags: c++, windows, opencv3.0

I'm trying to get the color(rgb value) under my cursor. When my is code compiled and i run it my program there is a box that says **"Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFBF64B3C58 in thing_1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0000001DA30FEFB0."**. When i press continue the box just comes back. I'm new to coding so it might be a newbie mistake and sorry for my messy code...

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

boolean k = true;

POINT cursorPosition;

HWND hWnd;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
 VideoCapture cap(0);

 while (1){
    Mat frame;

    bool bSuccess = cap.read(frame);

    imshow("Video", frame);

    if (waitKey(10) == 27){
        break;
    }

    if (k == true){
        hWnd = GetActiveWindow();
        k = false;
    }

     GetCursorPos(&cursorPosition);
     ScreenToClient(hWnd, &cursorPosition);

     if (cursorPosition.x < 0) {cursorPosition.x = 0;}
     if (cursorPosition.x > 640) {cursorPosition.x = 640;}
     if (cursorPosition.y < 0) {cursorPosition.y = 0;}
     if (cursorPosition.y > 479) {cursorPosition.y = 479;}

        Vec4b intensity = frame.at<Vec4b>(cursorPosition.x, cursorPosition.y);

        uchar blue = intensity.val[0];
        uchar green = intensity.val[1];
        uchar red = intensity.val[2];

        std::cout << "red = " << int(red) << " | green = " << int(green) << " | blue = " << int(blue) << " | X: " << cursorPosition.x << " |Y: " << cursorPosition.y << std::endl;
  }
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: When you ran the debugger, at which line of code did the error happen?

Comment: You aren't supposed to include `<WinUser.h>`, that's included by `Windows.h`. When you break in after seeing the exception message (click the "Break" button), what line of code does the debugger stop on?

Comment: You have an access to memory that is not allocated.  Try checking to make sure the cursorPosition pointer is valid before you use it to get the intensity.

Comment: @Rakurai how do you check if a non-pointer is a valid pointer?  cursorPosition is a POINT, not an LPPOINT so it isn't a pointer.

Comment: You are not checking for `bSuccess` anywhere.

Comment: @Eddge good point (ha), I misunderstood.

Comment: I found out that the problem disappears when i replace "cursorPosition.x" and "cursorPosition.y" with numbers like this: "Vec3b intensity = frame.at<Vec3b>(3, 3);"

Comment: Does `frame.at` expect screen-relative coordinates? I assume it does. In that case, calling `ScreenToClient` is wrong. `GetCursorPos` already returns the cursor's position in screen coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to finding the error was in getting the complete error message:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (((((sizeof(size_t)<<28)|0x8442211)>>((DataType<_Tp>::depth) & ((1 << 3) - 1))*4) & 15) == elemSize1()) in cv::Mat::at, file c:\users\tika\documents\visual studio projects\3rdparty\opencv-3.2\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp, line 957
```

The most important parts, being the file name and line number.  At line 957, file mat.inl.hpp we find this interesting bit of code:

```
CV_DbgAssert(CV_ELEM_SIZE1(DataType<_Tp>::depth) == elemSize1());
```

This is where the error comes from.  I'll let you investigate, but this really means that Mat expects the template paramater to the call to frame.at<>() to be a BYTE, as confirmed by a quick printout on stdout `std::cout >> frame.elemsize1().`

Here is my version of your program, it was a clinch to write after installing opencv. It's in C++14.

```
// ConsoleApplication1.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

//#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>


#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    HWND hwnd = ::GetConsoleWindow();
    if (hwnd == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Error ! hwnd is NULL\n";
        return 3;
    }

    auto cam = cv::VideoCapture::VideoCapture(0);
    auto frame = cv::Mat();
    POINT pnt = {};

    for (;;)
    {
        cam.grab();
        cam >> frame;

        ::GetCursorPos(&pnt);
        ::ScreenToClient(hwnd, &pnt);

        std::cout << frame.elemSize1() << "cx: " << frame.cols << " cy: " << frame.rows << " x: " << pnt.x << " y: " << pnt.y;

        if (0 < pnt.x && pnt.x < frame.cols
            && 0 < pnt.y && pnt.y < frame.rows)
        {
            const RGBTRIPLE& rgb = *reinterpret_cast<const RGBTRIPLE*>(&frame.at<BYTE>(pnt.y, pnt.x));

            std::cout << " color:"
                << std::setw(4)
                << (unsigned)rgb.rgbtRed
                << std::setw(4)
                << (unsigned)rgb.rgbtGreen
                << std::setw(4)
                << (unsigned)rgb.rgbtBlue;
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Hope this will help you in moving forward.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that GetActiveWindow returns a valid HWND?  Your console application does not have a window message queue.

A NULL hwnd will make your call to ScreenToClient fail, and the cursorPosition is still in screen coordinates.  To make your program work, you could start by:

- Call  GetConsoleWindow() to get the HWND, the returned value will be valid for the duration of your app, so only call it once.  Check that the HWND you get is not NULL!!
- Get the x, y size of frame, so you can check that your client-coordinates cursorPosition is within bounds. - That's very likely what causes the crash.
- Always check that cursorPosition is within the bounds of Mat frame before accessing it.  Bounds-checking is something that you should **always** do when accessing a table with coordinates that come from a third party.

Comment: Cool, what is the size of _frame_ in the x direction?

Comment: 'Should' will not make it work...  And what will you do when you'll want to  resize your window/track its size?  You can get the width by reading frame.cols.  you should always test for cursorPosition >= 0 && cursorPosition.x < frame.cols before calling frame.at().  Same goes for cursorPos.y and frame.rows,  It's also possible that rows and cols are inverted in the frame implementation, meaning x <--> y.  Which sounds likely.

Comment: The frame size to the x direction is definitely "640", and i added that checking code to my program.

Comment: If it bombs at 480,then the matrix is in row, column order.

Comment: But using the variables from _frame_ is the right way to do it.

Comment: Nothing seems to work i tried "Vec4b intensity = frame.at<Vec4b>(639, 479);" and "Vec4b intensity = frame.at<Vec4b>(479, 639);"... I think it's a bug or i'm using the wrong version of "OpenCV", or im just dumb.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know about opencv, but it seems your matrix needs to be initialized...  Sorry I thought

How about moving the declaration for frame out of the loop, and specifying its size and depth?  You could also move the call to GetConsoleWindow() out of there as well...  The top of your main() should then look like:

```
void main()
{
   VideoCapture cap(0);
   HWND hwnd = GetActiveWindow();
   if (!hwnd)
   {
       std::cout << "Error!!  hwnd is NULL\n";
       return 3;
   }
   Mat frame(640, 480, CV_U8C3);  

   while (1)
   {
      cap.grab();
      cap >> frame;

      // grab cursor pos
 etc...
```

...